# Impurity diffusion from solid to air

Tags: solid-state-physics, simulations, boundary-conditions, diffusion, gas

I have to put up a simple 1D model to simulate the diffusion of impurities in a bulk material, to a top thin layer made of another material, and compare it to experimental data.

I first did it with boundary Neumann conditions (no flow of particle at left of the main material or the right of the topping layer). Running simulations, the system reaches  equilibrium when the (non-zero) concentration is homogeneous and equal in both materials. 
However, experimental data do reach 0 concentration in the main material (big red part in the image below), which was very surprising to me (the thin layer on top has no reason to 'absorb' all impurities if we consider simple diffusion mechanisms). I will link an image of simulation results illustrating the problem :

[image: diffusion to a thin layer (from x=0 to 1e-5) plotted against time. normalized oncentration stabilizes to 0.8 while exp reaches 0]

(left : diffusion to a thin layer (represented from x=0 to 1e-5). Concentration is plotted against time t and position x.
Right : decreasing concentration in the main material against time)

When I mentionned this to my tutor, he mentionned that the top layer was in contact with air. He then told me with great confidence that the impurities thus diffused from the top layer to the air, allowing the diffusion process to go on till the main material exhausted his concentration.

I am quite surprised by this concept, as the timescale of the experiment is quite short (500h). Can a solid really diffuse in the air that quickly ? 
I have no idea how to **model properly the diffusion mechanisms of the impurities from the top solid layer to the air**. My tutor suggested setting a Dirichlet condition at the top boundary (C=0 at the solid/air interface). This doesn't seem physical at all to me, I have a hard time thinking that the concentration should be continuous at a solid/air interface. Plus, I gave it a try, and it fits the experimental trend rather poorly.

Could any of you recommend me some paper on the subject ? I would really like to know more about diffusion process from solid to gas phase which are very counter-ituitive to me as everyday objects don't seem to diffuse significantly in air on observable timescales (like here in 500h)

Comment: What were the impurities? It's conceivable that they collected on the surface for some reason, it wouldn't be the first time that it was entropically preferable for a solid to eject stuff that was inside of it.

Comment: I am not sure how much information I am allowed to give out as to the nature of the materials I am working with. I would rather continue the discussion without mentionning which precise materials are implied, if it is possible :)